# How to use printf with strings as arguments?

Tags: awk, printf

This code in `awk` doesn't work with `printf` :

```
var1 = "%-15s %-15s\n"
var2 = "\"oooo\",\"nnnn\""
var3 = var1 var2
printf var3

Updated :
no var3
printf var1,var2
```

And I want it **works** like :

```
printf "%-15s %-15s","oooo","nnnn"
```

because I'm building a visual results file of a parsing and I don't know in advance the number of arguments.
Is there any solution in **this way**?

Comment: In your example `var3` is just a string created from the concatenation of the strings held in the other variables, `var1`, and `var2`, so when you use it as `printf var3` you're using it as a formatting string with no data. At no point in your code do you even have 2 data items to use with `var1` as the formatting string so idk what it is you're really hoping will happen with your code. If you show us what you're trying to do rather than how you're trying to do it, then we can help.

Comment: @EdMorton : my issue was to find if a way exists to gather data from cols, to concatenate it in a String and after to format it with printf. But it looks that can't work because of the mandatory presence of commas between collected Strings outside to each String. As I said to JNevill I found another way which consists to format collected Strings before to concatenate them. It's possible enough than that issue haven't solution.

Comment: Without a [mcve] including concise, testable sample input and expected output idk if there's a solution or not as idk what exactly the problem is you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do the entire string like that as the commas are treated as string literals in the `printf` function when supplied through a single variable like that. You could do:

```
   var1 = "\"%-15s %-15s\n\"";
   var2 = "\"oooo\"";
   var3 = "\"nnnn\"";
   printf var1,var2,var3;
```

Comment: OK it works but it doesn't solve my problem because I don't know the number of arguments in advance. Perhaps an array intead of a variable.....

Comment: Instead of a string store your args in an array the iterate the array at the endand print.

Comment: I found another way, I convert each argument with printf before to concatenate them in a regular String. But I stand this post open because it could be helpfull.